# Merging several csv files creating a new column in the merged file having sample name in that column

Tags: r

I have several .csv files in a folder

```
   > list.files()
     [1] "LP2000325-DNA_A01.copynumber.caveman.csv"
     [2] "LP2000329-DNA_A01.copynumber.caveman.csv"


> a=read.csv("LP2000325-DNA_A01.copynumber.caveman.csv")
> class(a)
[1] "data.frame"
> str(a)
'data.frame':   109 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Chromosome: chr  "1" "1" "1" "2" ...
 $ Start     : int  61987 149657732 156631940 23368 37956452 38002857 68554641 70311223 92290293 92291779 ...
 $ End       : int  149656244 156631646 249205928 37956018 38002829 68553940 70308522 92290254 92290307 243164490 ...
 $ Total_CN  : int  2 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 7 2 ...
 $ Minor_CN  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
>
```

I want to merge these files and have a column by the name of each file in R as I don't have access to terminal

Comment: how do you want to merge? is there a column that they share or do they all have the same columns and you want to append them into one dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your desired output structure, my guess is that you want something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(file = list.files(),
       data = map(file, read.csv)) %>%
  unnest(data)
```